# Python Function return value for 1 iteration only

Tags: python, file, function, parsing

I do have following code where I am its doing following thing.

1. Parsing Whole file and checking for patter in each line. If the pattern exists, it should return that pattern to main function and print the value.

Issue: The function is only returning 1st pattern and do not check for same pattern into multiple lines.

code:

```
import re
import sys
import os


def find_pattern(file):
    with open(file) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if "abc" in line:
                return line
            else:
                continue

def check(file):
    return_list = []
    data=find_pattern(file)

    if data != None:
        return_list.append(data)

    if not data:
        return "working"
    else:
        return return_list

if __name__== '__main__':
    file = sys.argv[1]
    print check(file)
```

If the file has multiple line containing abc, it will print only 1st line and skip other lines. I want to print all lines that contains abc.

Sample file

```
     sdfdsffdabcafsfse
     asasssadfsdadsadsaddsadadabc
     asfasfdsafdfabc
```

output with above code:

```
     sdfdsffdabcafsfse
```

Comment: Don't you know `return` can terminate the function body?

Comment: Although this is a relatively straight forward problem, it includes a small, self contained example, with sample input and output. This is by all definitions a "good question", so its unfair to downvote the OP just because someone deems it "too trivial".

Answer (score 1):

You are prematurely returning from the function on this line:

```
return line
```

Which means you exit the function and the loop ceases to iterate assoon as the first instance is found.

Consider something like this instead, where you capture and return *all* matches:

```
def find_pattern(file):
    out = []
    with open(file) as fp:
      for line in fp:
          if "abc" in line:
              out.append(line)
          else:
               continue
    return out
```

Alternatively, you can manage this in a single, simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def find_pattern(file):
    with open(file) as fp:
        return [line for line in fp if "abc" in line]
```